# Why does Ubuntu 16.04.3 work faster than Ubuntu 17.10 on VirtualBox (Mac OS X)?

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, graphics, 17.10

I have VirtualBox 5.2 installed on Mac OS X 10.12.5.

Ubuntu 16.04.3, with 3d acceleration enabled, gets about 40-50fps

Ubuntu 17.10, with 3d acceleration enabled or disabled, gets about 10-15fps

All the configs are similar for both virtual machines (size of ram, hdd, gpu memory, Guest Additions installed on both machines, etc).

Why does it work like this?

Comment: My hunch is 16.04 is using the **xorg** desktop engine and 17.10 is using the **Wayland** desktop engine.

Comment: Wasn't Wayland supposed to be faster the Xorg?

Comment: @mikewhatever: In the end yes, but that includes a bunch of assumptions like proper display driver support and performance optimizations. Who knows what that means for virtual display drivers and all the hacks that are necessary to provide hardware acceleration through it. This may improve in the future when Wayland becomes more popular but I wouldn't be surprised if the developers of commercial VMs have other priorities than desktop graphics performance.